# primefaces clock server mode not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i am implementing primefaces clock on my web page like below

```
<p:clock id="clockID"   pattern="HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy"  mode="server" />
```

in my server time is

```
Thu May 22 08:27:21 UTC 2014
```

but if i run the page it shows client side time.... according to my understanding 
`mode = server` means the page should display the time of the server, If my understanding is correct i am getting a wrong time on the page.

Is there any other way to display simple clock on jsf page without using primefaces.

Comment: but it will not perform like clock

Comment: Yes, i thought you talked in the end about simpler way to just display the current time. Sorry, i'd remove the comment.

Comment: thanks Omar for the link i used primefaces poll to display the clock

Comment: @Ramakrishna did you got any solution for this question?

Comment: @Jeevanantham i upgraded to earlier version and the issue resolved.